User input is not visible in jupyter notebook export to html
I am taking a python course and I want to save lecture notebooks as a PDF.
For this I save this notebook first in html then save it in PDF. It would have been wonderful to see the user inputs in html - how can I do it?
An example:
a = input()
print(a)

I typed 123654 in jupyter and I can see this input: notebook screenshot
When I export it to html I the input is not visible: notebook exported as html file
I searched, but haven't found anything useful.
